# Access DSUM with multiple variables including dates derived from date parts

Tags: ms-access, calculated-columns

Really hoping for guidance.

I'm calculating a running 3 month total in an Access query. two of the DSUM variables are strings and the third is a date that i derive from date parts.

The string variables I passing in are working fine, but I'm having a hard time getting the date range to work in the statement.

Here's what's working:
Running_TOT: `DSum(" [SumOfCNTRCTL_ADJSTMT_AMT] ","tbl_processed_accts","[PYR]='" & [PYR] & "'and [PT_TYPE_CD]='" & [PT_TYPE_CD] & "'")`

The following needs to be added in a third and clause:

```
DateSerial([DSCHRG_YR],[DSCHRG_MNTH],1)
```

BETWEEN

```
DateAdd("m",-2,DateSerial([DSCHRG_YR],[DSCHRG_MNTH],1))
```

AND

```
DateAdd("m",1,DateSerial([DSCHRG_YR],[DSCHRG_MNTH],1))-1
```

I think I've read every DSUM post on the internet looking for ideas. Eternal gratitude for anyone who can lend a hand getting the syntax right..

Thanks.

Comment: it's not about topic, but may be it is better to use 1 function `DateSerial([DSCHRG_YR],[DSCHRG_MNTH],1)` not 3 as you do when call `cdate([DSCHRG_MNTH] & "/1/" & [DSCHRG_YR])`

Comment: What field holds Date value to select? Do [DSCHRG_YR] and [DSCHRG_MNTH] hold desired year and month?

Comment: I'll make the change to dateserial instead of cdate. Thanks for the recommendation. [dschrg_yr] has values 2012,2013,2014. [dschrg_mnth] has values 1-12 representing months.  Thanks!

Comment: it seems 'third and clause' is always true because the first day of month is always between previous two months and one next month

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is a 3 month running total for unique combinations of [pyr] and [pt_type-cd]. It's possible that im conceptualizing the dates wrong. I know the first statement works, if I added the dates as above to the existing statement, wouldnt it produce the sum of [SumOfCNTRCTL_ADJSTMT_AMT] for unique[pyr] and [pt_type_cd] within the past 3 months?

Comment: Do you want to filter records which have [DSCHRG_YR] and [DSCHRG_MNTH] in range 'last 3 month'?